# Curve: Bevel object faces wrong direction, how to fix?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, bevel

so I created a curve and applied the profile of a cornice as bevel to it in order to quickly wrap a cornice around a building. My Problem is, that the resulting cornice is facing inwards though, as opposed to outwards as it's supposed to. Is there a solution other than rotating the profile object itself to fix this?

[image]

I am using this profile for a cornice on a different location as well, where it is properly facing outwards, so rotating it for this cornice would just cause the very same problem on the other cornice.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to switch the direction of your spline.

It's a possibility you might want to consider, although to be frank, it's a mystery to me. Here's a curve comprising two 2D splines. The only difference between the splines is that the one on the right has been subdivided.

[image]

For some reason, switching the direction of the splines twists the spline on the right by 90 degrees, and has no effect on the spline on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: So as Duarte points out, the following solution works if your curve is 3D, and scaling negatively is probably the best idea in your case.

You can play with the vertex *Tilt* value: select the curve, switch to *Edit* mode, select all the vertices and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> 180, or open the *N* panel > *Item > Mean Tilt* > 180:

[image]

Comment: Tilt only works for 3D curves which cause distortions on corners, it also only rotates the profile, doesn't hadle mirroring which seems to be the OP issue. Things that may work here are mirroring the bevel object, scaling it negatively, or inverting directions on either the curve or the bevel object

Comment: How can I invert the direction on the curve? I don't want to edit the bevel object in this case.

Comment: oh ok I may have missed something, that said you can avoid distortions on corners with 3D curves, it depends on its shape, but scaling negatively is probably the best idea